# Does internal communication between private servers use DNS and HTTPS?

Tags: networking, https, reverse-proxy, internals

I would like to know how internal communication links between private internal servers and a reverse proxy look.

When from my client (browser) I make a request to, say https://facebook.com, I hit Facebook's reverse proxy. I have two questions, when that reverse proxy gets a request and needs to forward it to the server that should handle it, does that sever it is forwarding the request to have a domain name or is it just an IP address ((user.facebook.com or useroffacebook.com v.s. 34.23.66.25 (DO NOT GO TO THAT ADDRESS I JUST MADE IT UP!!!)))? Also, does that connection use HTTP or HTTPS?

Comment: It could be both the DNS and/or IPs behind the reverse proxy as per your use-case. Same goes for http/https.

Comment: "_(DO NOT GO TO THAT ADDRESS I JUST MADE IT UP!!!)))_" Do not make up addresses that do not belong to you. IANA has set aside three IPv4 address ranges (`192.0.2.0/24`, `198.51.100.0/24`, and `203.0.113.0/24`) and one IPv6 address range (`2001:db8::/32`) for such examples, and if you use addressing in those ranges, people will know they are just examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Kshitij Joshi already mentioned, it could be both.

A more detailed perspective for implementation:

- reverse proxy **should** use IP addresses for routing so they are still working even if the DNS fails or is unavailable to the proxy for some reason.
- internal traffic **should** also be encrypted (HTTPS). using plain text, even in internal networks, must be considered dangerous and is not recommended.

from my mindset you can replace the 'should' with a 'must'.